# What is the name of the following theorem?

Tags: complex-numbers, plane-geometry

I chanced upon this interesting theorem which states the following:

On the sides of parallelogram $ABCD$, squares are constructed exterior to it. Then, their centers, $M_1, M_2, M_3 \text{ and } M_4 $ are themselves vertices of a square. [image]

Also, does anyone knows of similar interesting theorems which I may prove using complex numbers? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a more general context, that's a consequence of the [Napoleon-Barlotti theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon%27s_theorem#Napoleon-Barlotti_theorem)

[image]

Comment: Hi @gimusi, thanks for your reply. Based on the suggested theorem, I found my answer here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thébault%27s_theorem

Comment: @Cleytus Well done! You are welcome bye